# Why is alarm and SIGALRM undeclared?

Tags: alarm

I am trying to compile the sources of a chess program which includes these, I think, relevant lines:

```
    #include <sys/time.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <signal.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include "timectrl.h"
    #include "search.h"
    #include "plp.h"
    #include "uci.h"
    #include "util.h"
    #include <winsock2.h>
    ...
    signal(SIGALRM, timectrl_alarm);
```

However, the compilation fails and I get these messages:

```
timectrl.c: In function 'timectrl_go':
timectrl.c:59:12: error: 'SIGALRM' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'SIGABRT'?
   59 |     signal(SIGALRM, timectrl_alarm);
      |            ^~~~~~~
      |            SIGABRT
timectrl.c:59:12: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
timectrl.c:63:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'alarm' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   63 |     alarm(1);
      |     ^~~~~
```

I don't understand why these are undeclared when they must be in the included libraries.

Can you help please?

Comment: Are you trying to compile in a Linux environment? Does the compiler report errors before complaining about SIGALRM and alarm()?

Comment: I am on Windows. The compiler (gcc 12.1) only complained about those two.

Comment: Well, AFAIK Windows doesn't support signals in a way Unix/Linux does. You'll have to replace the code with Windows logic. That won't be a trivial task though. If you are interested in the chess program itself, set up a Linux and try to compile it there.

Comment: Thanks Ronald. I am not a programmer so I think I'll simply abandon the idea.